# springframework version 5.0.5.RELEASE Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/task/AsyncListenableTaskExecutor

Tags: java, spring, osgi, apache-karaf, stomp

> Unable to initialize bean
>   org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to initialize bean

I'm trying to use Spring STOMP message handler over Jetty Websocket

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do below steps:
If you are using STS/Eclipse then
`Right click on project -> Maven -> Update project -> Select Force Update Snapshots/Release and OK`.
Or you can `update your maven from terminal` if you are using `IntelliJ IDEA`.
This is happening because, it's not able to find out specific jar/class.